# ¿Como puedo generar el texto al presionar el BOTON con Javascrpt?

Tags: javascript

Buenas espero que se encuentren muy bien.
Estoy desarrollando un generador de preguntas, como puedo hacer que cuando escriba un texto en el input text y precione el boton de GENERAR PREGUNTAS, me genere las preguntas en la parte de abajo, de forma igual con GENERAR RESPUESTAS pero estas con input de type radio para poder seleccionar la respuesta, y asi secuencialmente una debajo de otra. ¿Que Scrpt puedo utilizar? Les agradezco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te pongo los pasos.

1. Almacena los selectores de los inputs.(P.ejemplo con document.querySelector(selector))
2. Escucha los eventos onClick de los buttons.
3. Cuando salte el evento onClick, rellena el campo value del input requerido. (P.ejemplo: $preguntaInput.value = "Nueva pregunta").

Son los pasos, no el script. Así practicas con unas directrices. Si tienes cualquier otra duda ya sabes ;)